# Error getting results on KQL using ipv4_lookup and watchlist functions

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I run a KQL search to enrich with some network tagging from a watchlist and then use it to filter out the results, based in all Microsoft documentation, code ir right, but results are wrong

```
let subnets = (_GetWatchlist('NetworkHierarchy')| where GROUP in ("Zscaler")|project CIDR, GROUP);
let Query =
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(timeFrame);
Query
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(subnets, IPAddress, CIDR, return_unmatched = true)
| where isempty(CIDR)
```

I get results of the main "query" but aren't enriched, one example is a result from 165.225.208.47 IP address when I have the entire 165.225.0.0/16 block on that Watchlist

I tried a lot of variations but seems is unable to match, I have only 5K entries in that watchlist, similiar like

[watchlist_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3M5f.png)

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off the mark here, and apologies if so.  But have you tried [`materialize`](https://let%20subnets%20=%20materialize(_GetWatchlist(%27NetworkHierarchy%27)%7C%20where%20GROUP%20in%20(%22Zscaler%22)%7Cproject%20CIDR,%20GROUP);%20let%20Query%20=%20SigninLogs%20%7C%20where%20TimeGenerated%20%3E=%20ago(timeFrame);%20Query%20%7C%20evaluate%20ipv4_lookup(subnets,%20IPAddress,%20CIDR,%20return_unmatched%20=%20true)%20%7C%20where%20isempty(CIDR)) on the watchlist?

```
let subnets = materialize(_GetWatchlist('NetworkHierarchy')| where GROUP in ("Zscaler")|project CIDR, GROUP);
let Query =
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(timeFrame);
Query
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(subnets, IPAddress, CIDR, return_unmatched = true)
| where isempty(CIDR)
```

Comment: It didn't work, also it's not within Microsoft documentation or examples, that's why I didn't think of before, but thank you